# Python - pegar dados de arquivo .txt com regex

Tags: python, regex, arquivo

ola, estou tentando fazer um programinha mas não estou conseguido retirar os dados do arquivo .txt, seriam mais ou menos esses em negrito.

```
PokerStars Hand #135235596385: Tournament #1228747530, $0.23+$0.02 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level I (10/20) - 2015/05/14 3:30:05 BRT [2015/05/14 2:30:05 ET]
```

tipo.. tenho de pegar a chave 'Hand' com os dados depois de '#' terminando em ':', a mesma coisa para 'Tournament' pego dados depois de '#' e terminando em ',' para salvar em um dicionario...

d = {'Hand' : 135235596385, 'Tournament' : 1228747530 }

seria mais ou menos isso.

Comment: O que é que já tentaste? Existe algum padrão nesses dados ou no conteúdo que queres extrair?

Comment: Não estou entendendo o regex rsrs, o padra seria... na primeira linham depois de "Hand #" pegar "135235596385" depois de "Tournament #" pegar "1228747530" acho que só com isso ja da pra mim me virar e ir implementando pra pegar os outros dados.

Comment: Forneça um exemplo na pergunta (clique no botão editar) de como devem ficar os dados "extraídos" dentro do vetor.

Comment: Adelson a pergunta continua muito vaga. Dá uma olhada aqui: https://regex101.com/r/lZ4vZ9/1 e podes [edit] a pergunta para acrescentar mais detalhes para clarificar.

Comment: @AdelsonInácio, você precisa só da regex pra pegar esse numero?

Comment: acho que não, da forma que for melhor pra pegar esses dados.

Comment: @AdelsonInácio, bom não sei se é isso que precisa, mas para pegar sempre o que vem depois de Tournament #, ficaria assim ((?<=Tournament\s#)\d*) , a mesma coisa para o Hand, é isso que precisa?

Answer (score 2):

Levando em consideração que o arquivo pode conter várias linhas como essa e sempre o valor de **Hand** vem antes do valor de **Tournament**, você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
>>> import re
>>> pokerstars = []
>>> with open('my_file.txt', 'r') as f:
...     for line in f:
...         data = (re.findall(r'#(\d+)[:,]', line))
...         pokerstars.append({'hand': data[0], 'tournament': data[1]})
... 
>>> pokerstars
[{'tournament': '1228747530', 'hand': '135235596385'}]
```

A forma mais *pythonica* de ler um arquivo de texto é através do *context manager* (o **with** no caso).

O método **findall** do pacote **re** (*regex*) retorna uma lista de ocorrências que bateram com a regex especificada.

Comment: Legal -  resposta está correta, mas não há motivo para fazer dois `for`  - você pode perfeitamente pegar os dados e coloca-los num dicionário dentro do primeiro `for`.  
A outra dica é evitar ao máximo usar uma variável de nome `l`  - por que prejudica a legibilidade por ser difícil disntiguier entre `l, I, 1`  (o "i" maiúsculo na fonte em que digito o comentário aqui por exemplo é idêntico ao "l" minúsculo. A fonte de exibição do comentário mostra diferente)

Comment: Tem razão, melhorei o código (Y).

Answer (score 0):

Basta procurar pela sequência de dígitos após as palavras-chave. No seu exemplo:

```
>>> str = "PokerStars Hand #135235596385: Tournament #1228747530, $0.23+$0.02 USD Hold'em No Limit - Level I (10/20) - 2015/05/14 3:30:05 BRT [2015/05/14 2:30:05 ET]"

>>> d = {'Hand':       re.search(r'Hand #(\d+)', str).group(1),
         'Tournament': re.search(r'Tournament #(\d+)', str).group(1)}

>>> d
{'Tournament': '1228747530', 'Hand': '135235596385'}
```

A regex está detalhadamente explicada em http://regexr.com/3b2e2